# Number of subsets with the same cardinality

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Suppose we have a set $S$ with  cardinal number $n$, such that $n+n = n$. Consider the set, T, of all subsets with cardinality $n$. How can I show that the cardinality of $T$ is $2^n$? (Without the Axiom of Choice)

Comment: $n+n=n$ which means $n=0$

Comment: Not for cardinal numbers...

Comment: choose 0,1,2...n elements from the set n..

Comment: How do I choose elements without the axiom of choice?

Comment: The fact that $|S|=n$ & $n+n=n$ means that $S$ is an infinite set. The set $T$ is a way of describing the power set of $S$. So you need to show that the cardinality of the power set of $T$ is $2^n$. So you could show $T=\mathcal{P}(S)$ is bijectively equivalent to the set $2^n$

Comment: @rt6 Or that S is the empty set. :P I tried coming up with an injection from the power set into $T$. I couldn't think of one.

Comment: @rt6 This is not the power set: e.g. for the natural numbers we'd only want all subsets that are the same size as the natural numbers, not all finite ones, which *are* in the power set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $|T| \leq 2^n$ since $T$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(S)$ which has cardinality $2^n$.

As the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem does not require Choice, it suffices to show that the reverse inequality holds.

Since $n + n = n$ the sets $S$ and $S \times \{ 0,1 \}$ have the same cardinality.  It follows that the set $X$ of all subsets of $S \times \{0,1\}$ of cardinality $n$ has the same cardinality as the set $T$, so we need only show that $2^n \leq |X|$.

For each subset $A$ of $S$, the set $(A \times \{ 0 \}) \cup (S \times \{ 1 \})$ is a subset of $S \times \{ 0,1 \}$ of cardinality $n$, and so belongs to $X$. The obvious mapping is injective, which then shows that $2^n = | \mathcal{P} (S) | \leq |X|$.

Comment: Ugh, so simply! Thanks.

Comment: @Bob: You're welcome!